# What is a difference between op_kwargs and templates_dict od PythonOperator in Airflow?

Tags: python, airflow

I am wondering what is a difference in usage between `op_kwargs` and `templates_dict` in Airflow, since both are templated fields in `PythonOperator` `template_fields= ['templates_dict', 'op_args', 'op_kwargs']`.

I checked the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/python/index.html#airflow.operators.python.PythonOperator) but it's still not clear for me:

```
op_kwargs (Optional[Mapping[str, Any]]) – a dictionary of keyword arguments that will get unpacked in your function

templates_dict (Optional[Dict[str, Any]]) – a dictionary where the values are templates that will get templated by the Airflow engine sometime between __init__ and execute takes place and are made available in your callable’s context after the template has been applied. (templated)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`op_kwargs`** (Optional[Mapping[str, Any]]): This is the dictionary we use **to pass in user-defined key-value pairs** to our python callable function

**`templates_dict`** (Optional[Dict[str, Any]]): This is the dictionary that airflow uses **to pass the default variables** as key-value pairs to our python callable function. E.g., the **'task_instance'** or **'run_id'** are a couple of variables that airflow provides us by default. The full list of default variables is [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.1/code.html#default-variables).

**So technically, we just need to pass the additional key-value pairs we need through the `op_kwargs` parameter while using the `PythonOperator`.**  I think that's the intended design choice, but we could still use either to pass in our key-value pairs.

Airflow takes care of the rest. The `execute` method in the `PythonOperator` merges the `kwargs` and `templates_dict` into a single dictionary, which we later unpack in the `python_callable` function, generally using either `**kwargs` or `**context`. Airflow code for this is [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/40765307d8c2febbeaddff61551cbfa9d717522e/airflow/operators/python.py#L168).

Answer (score -1):

To add to Jash's answer

In Apache Airflow, both `op_kwargs` and `templates_dict` are templated fields that can be used in the `PythonOperator` to provide additional context or parameters to the Python callable function being executed as a task. However, they serve different purposes and have different usage scenarios:

**`op_kwargs`:**
`op_kwargs` stands for "operator keyword arguments."
It allows you to pass static or templated key-value pairs as keyword arguments to the Python callable function.
These keyword arguments are accessible within the Python function as regular function arguments.
Use cases for `op_kwargs` include passing configuration parameters, flags, or other static values needed by the Python function.

**`templates_dict`:**
`templates_dict` is a dictionary of values that can be templated using Airflow's Jinja templating engine.
It allows you to provide dynamic or context-specific values to the Python function.
Unlike `op_kwargs`, the entire dictionary is passed as a single argument to the Python function.
Use cases for `templates_dict` include passing dynamic values such as execution dates (`{{ ds }}`), task instance details (`{{ ti.xcom_pull(...) }}`), or any other templated values.
Key Differences:

**Granularity:**
`op_kwargs` allows you to specify individual key-value pairs, providing granularity in parameter passing.
`templates_dict`, on the other hand, provides a single dictionary object that can contain multiple templated values.

**Static vs. Dynamic Values:**
`op_kwargs` is typically used for passing static or predetermined values to the Python function.
`templates_dict` is used for passing dynamic or context-dependent values that may vary between task executions.

Example:

```
from airflow. Models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2024, 1, 1),
}

def my_python_function(**kwargs):
    op_kwargs_value = kwargs.get('op_kwargs_value')
    templates_dict_value = kwargs.get('templates_dict_value')
    print(f"op_kwargs_value: {op_kwargs_value}")
    print(f"templates_dict_value: {templates_dict_value}")

with DAG('example_dag', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='@daily') as dag:
    task1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='python_task',
        python_callable=my_python_function,
        op_kwargs={'op_kwargs_value': 'static_value'},
        templates_dict={'templates_dict_value': '{{ ds }}'})
```

In this example:
`op_kwargs` is used to pass the static value `'static_value'` to the Python function.
templates_dict is used to pass the dynamic value `{{ ds }}` (execution date) to the Python function.